# Can I Change ListView style Android without building custom listview?

Tags: android, listview

I would like to change text and back ground color of my Listview without building custom rows. Is this possible ?

Here is my code which is NOT working.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:textColor="#000000"           
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#000000"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, `cacheColorHint` has nothing to do with style.
Try watching [Romain Guy's ListView presentation on the GoogleIO 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70). You will understand a lot with it.

About the style:

I have changed a few things on my app.

View with the ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
  android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
  android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
  android:dividerHeight="1dip"
  android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
/>
```

Short explanation:
I just left the footerDivider and changed my divider to a gradient.

drawable/list_divider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:centerColor="#CCCCCC"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:height="1px"
                android:angle="0" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

RowLayout:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
```

Explanation:
Added a white background.